# Ubuntu Server can't Access the apache outside localhost

Tags: ubuntu, port

I know this question is already posted alot but I already read them all and not solve my problem.

I already have fresh install ubuntu 20.04 with fresh installed mysql,phpmyadmin,apache

when i open my http://localhost/phpmyadmin its work perfectly fine, but the problem is when im connecting it to other pc with different ip, its only display "this site can't be reach" I also allow all the ip from my ufw, i check it if its open.

this is some of my information

Ubuntu Information:

- No LSB modules are available.
- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
- Release:        20.04
- Codename:       focal

Using this cmd to check my port :

- $ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
- tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      952/mysqld
- tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      952/mysqld
- tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      809/systemd-resolve
- tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      899/sshd: /usr/sbin
- tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      924/apache2
- tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      899/sshd: /usr/sbin

$ nmap -p 80 localhost

- Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-01-14 04:30 UTC
- Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
- Host is up (0.000069s latency).

- PORT   STATE SERVICE
- 80/tcp open  http

I also allowed it in ufw

$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

- 22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
- Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere
- 443                       ALLOW       Anywhere
- 80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
- 80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
- 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
- Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
- 443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
- 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
- 80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

i also use this cmd

- sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

when I check my port in online tools the all port is close Except 22
which is im using in ssh

why I can open the 22 port and use ssh but my other port still close?

anyone can give me an idea why

- this my router port
  [image: I also enable the port in my router]

Comment: Seems that Apache only listens to IPv6, Is that by design?

Comment: this is fresh install ubuntu and all of application, so i dont know. Should i change that?

Comment: in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf `, what does the line with `Listen` say? Should be `Listen 80`

Comment: I dont have that dir, what I have is /etc/apache2/ports.conf  Idk if they are the same but inside is 
`Listen 0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: hm, that should be ok. What does your virtual host definition say? something like `<VirtualHost *:80>`?

Comment: yes, and default text

Comment: @LjmDullaart Listening on IPv6 only is normal and IPv4 connections are allowed here. For Ace, can you provide an `nmap` output from the pc that you're trying to connect from?

Comment: @doneal24 hello, I dont know if this is what you looking for but i try nmap localhost 
```Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-01-14 21:26 +04
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000050s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
631/tcp  open  ipp
3306/tcp open  mysql```

Comment: @Ace What I was asking for is an `nmap` scan from the PC running the browser against the system with the web server. Also, please edit your question when you add information since comments are transient and are not easily searched.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.